# Flutter Firebase Database startat paginate

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, pagination

i'd like to know how to do paginate data using flutter and firebase database, here my data structure:

[image]

I am trying do this way:

```
_getItems() async {
    setState(() {
      _loading = true;
    });
    Query query = Database.getReferenceFrases(widget.categoria.key)
        .orderByKey()
        .limitToFirst(_num_items);

    DataSnapshot snapshot = await query.once();

    Map values = snapshot.value;

    values.forEach((key, data) {
      Frase frase = Frase.fromJson(key, data);
      print(frase.key);

      _frases.add(frase);
    });

    setState(() {
      _loading = false;
    });
  }
```

This is the method to get more data:

```
 _getMoreItems() async {
        print('called');
        if (!_hasMore) {
          return;
        }
        if (_loadingMore) {
          return;
        }

        _loadingMore = true;

        Query query = Database.getReferenceFrases(widget.categoria.key)
            .orderByKey()
            .startAt(_lastItem)
            .limitToFirst(_num_items);

        DataSnapshot snapshot = await query.once();

        Map values = snapshot.value;

        if (values.length < _num_items) {
          _hasMore = false;
        }

        values.forEach((key, data) {
          Frase frase = Frase.fromJson(key, data);
          print(frase.key);

          _frases.add(frase);
        });

        setState(() {
          _loadingMore = false;
        });

      }
```

And then when i call getMoreItems i get the last key from the list this way:

```
 _lastItem = _frases[_frases.length - 1].key;
```

The problem is that i am getting the same data every time, not getting next data:

```
I/flutter ( 5885): -KY9YGChAX-GxRX5ztFz
I/flutter ( 5885): -KY9YKb5f7OORGd0mHA3
I/flutter ( 5885): -KY9YOWsZckgO-_S_gGb
I/flutter ( 5885): -KY9YYNWp4J9wlxr08HN
I/flutter ( 5885): -KY9YSraznJYQrUecv9q
I/flutter ( 5885): -KY9Y92vEybWi6rVKJG3
I/flutter ( 5885): -KY9YCeYbN68RdlpAelG

I/flutter ( 5885): called
I/flutter ( 5885): -KY9YGChAX-GxRX5ztFz
I/flutter ( 5885): -KY9YasX8LJN2ZcMe8CU
I/flutter ( 5885): -KY9YKb5f7OORGd0mHA3
I/flutter ( 5885): -KY9YOWsZckgO-_S_gGb
I/flutter ( 5885): -KY9YYNWp4J9wlxr08HN
I/flutter ( 5885): -KY9YSraznJYQrUecv9q
I/flutter ( 5885): -KY9YCeYbN68RdlpAelG
```

Printing the _lastItem value just before call getMoreItems method i get this value:

```
I/flutter ( 5318): last key = -KY9YCeYbN68RdlpAelG
```

If i hard code using the first key instead of the last it returns different values, maybe it is reversed?

Comment: If you print the value of `_lastItem` right before you call `startAt()`, what does it output? If that seems the correct value, can you reproduce the problem with a hard-coded value?

Comment: Also: I don't see anywhere where you're clearing `_frases`. If that's indeed not in your app, you'll always end up showing the first page of data too, simply because that's what you loaded first.

Comment: Please don't provide long descriptions, log output, or code in comments. Click the edit link under your question to add it there.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am calling getItems in the method initState, then with a scroll listener i call getMoreItems when it reach the end of the list, then it just repeat, and goind add more and more. As shows in the last edit.

Comment: If i hard code the last key after call the first time and then use the first key printed instead of the last one, it loads different values, maybe the results are reversed?

Comment: Firebase doesn't reverse any values. It sounds like your the way you set the "last key" isn't working correcting. Running the code in a debugger, or logging the value at the correct time, should show if that's the case.

Comment: I will try debug and see where I am wrong. Thank you for the ideas.